# How to get my site visitor's IP address in php

Tags: php

using `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` is not providing the client's ip address.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Client machine may be behind an proxy or a NATed network connection. Try HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR or REMOTE_ADDR as well

Comment: [**How to get the client IP address in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Try  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']. That will give you your clients remote IP.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

- $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
- $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
- $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Comment: **NOTE:** Make sure you take look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php#comment50230065_3003233), before just using $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']